# Validation for save button

Tags: android, database, sqlite, validation, save

I've difficulty in creating a validation before saving it to [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite), below is the code:

```
public void save(View v){
    String weight = weightinputid.getText().toString();
    String bmi = BMIfinal.getText().toString();
    String status = BMIStatus.getText().toString();


    long id = data.insertData(weight, bmi, status);

    if(id<0){
        message.mess(this, "Error");
    }
    else{
        message.mess(this, "BMI has been saved");
    }
}
```

How do I create a validation if all the textfields are empty? my problem right now, even if i pressed the save button, the empty textfields was saved inside the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try this, to check if value is not entered in the `EditText`.

```
if (weight .equals(""))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Value1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if (bmi.equals(""))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Value2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
if (status.equals(""))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter Value3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use **`.matches("")`** instead of `.equals("")`

**UPDATE**

As @Rajesh mentioned in his comments, you can also use

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(weightinputid.getText())
```

to achieve the same functionality.

Comment: you can also use weight.isEmpty() instead of weight.equals().

Comment: @RajeshJadav Then it should be `TextUtils.isEmpty(weightinputid.getText())`

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do @Lal suggestion but in case the N fields are empty it's going to show the N toasts, and that's not very useful:

I'll suggest to do the following one of the following options:

a) Implement [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText):
Check the details here:
https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Min Characters"
        app:met_minCharacters="1" />
```

b) Use a TextWatcher and enable the SaveButton only after you have your required fields with values:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html
You can see how to it with the following question:
[Disable Button when Edit Text Fields empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682865/disable-button-when-edit-text-fields-empty)